# How to run a macro "OnEnterSlide" or "OnLeaveSlide" in Powerpoint VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there some kind of event which allows to run a macro any time one enters a slide or leave a slide ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SlideShowNextSlide or OnSlideShowPageChange

You can find the full list at http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html

Code sample from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211571%28office.11%29.aspx

---

This example determines the slide position for the slide following the 
SlideShowNextSlide event.

If  the next slide is slide three, the example changes 
the type of pointer to a pen and the pen color to red.

```
Private Sub App_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

Dim Showpos As Integer

Showpos = Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition + 1


 If Showpos = 3 Then  
     With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View
        .PointerColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .PointerType = ppSlideShowPointerPen
     End With
  Else
     With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View
        .PointerColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .PointerType = ppSlideShowPointerArrow
     End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is just for entering. I don't know if there is an event on "leaving"

Comment: I try to trigger it by executing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979950/how-to-automatically-trigger-the-app-object-initialization-in-powerpoint in execution window but doesn't seem to work. Did I mischief something ?

Comment: Answered in the other question

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that event to use really depends on the version of PowerPoint.
For me (PP 2007) the next event works quite stable:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal objWindow As SlideShowWindow)
   Debug.Print objWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex ' you can use this to check which slide invokes the event
End Sub
```

This code does not need additional class structures (PPTEvent).
But if you plan to use other events it's a good idea to put initialization of this class into *OnSlideShowPageChange*.

Please note, this code copes with the first part of the task given - entering the slide.
You may ask "What about its leaving?". Well, this is a matter of relativity. What's *entering* for one slide is at the same time *leaving* for another. Just use *objWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex* to track the current slide, compare it with the previous slide's index and decide if you've just left the needed one.