# How to automatically trigger the App Object initialization in Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

It is said here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211599%28v=office.11%29.aspx

> Before the procedure will run, you
>   must connect the declared object in
>   the class module (App in this example)
>   with the Application  object. You can
>   do this with the following code from
>   any module.
>
> Dim X As New EventClassModule Sub
>   InitializeApp()
>       Set X.App = Application End Sub
>
> Run the InitializeApp procedure.

Run HOW ? By hand ? I want it to automatically run when opening the powerpoint rather. Is there any way ?

Comment: Good point. I just gave them exactly that feedback when I saw that bull. Microsoft's entire PPT scripting shazzam is probably maintained by a single guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do that in the Auto_Open macro.

See for example http://skp.mvps.org/autoevents.htm

Comment: yep, this is the only way with VBA (so long as `Auto_Open` is used in an add-in).

Comment: Oh my I just checked the answer  almost 10 years later :D