# How do I update the slide master from Slideshow Mode and refresh current slide using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to have a counter in all slides of a powerpoint presentation.
The counter needs be controlled by a button in all slides that increases it.

I can do it for one specific slide, but when I do it with a slide master it doesn't refresh the screen during Slideshow mode. I have to exit slideshow and enter again to see the changes.

Code that doesn't refresh in Slideshow mode:

```
ctr = ctr + 1
ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ctr
```

Code that works (but only applies to one slide, not all slides in presentation):

```
ctr = ctr + 1
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Counter").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ctr
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the second method works for one slide, why don't you just implement a `For ... Next` loop over all of the slides in the presentation?

Comment: The counter needs to appear in all slides. For that to work I would have to use a macro to add the shape to each slide individually. But then if I wanted to change the size of the shape I have to use code for that too. Not very elegant...would rather force the refresh somehow and use a master slide for the shape.

Comment: It's no longer clear what you're asking. You might consider showing more of your code, because the two lines you've offered don't make much sense in context of your comment. Why isn't this shape on all of the slides? Why would it be too cumbersome to add ~5-10 lines of code to create the shape if it doesn't exist? Etc.

Comment: AFAIK, manipulating the `SlideMaster` during presentation mode will not alter the presentation, as you've observed. You need to manipulate the slide(s) directly.

Comment: I thought there would be a way to refresh the slides in presentation mode after altering the SlideMaster. Only way I found is to exit and re-enter presentation mode, but it doesn't always work.

The reason is to make it easier to change the shape without using code and creating the shape in all the slides.

Answer (score 2):

If your second method works, why not loop it?

```
Dim sld as Slide

ctr = ctr + 1
For Each sld in ActivePresentation.Slides
    sld.Shapes("Counter").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ctr
Next
```

NB: This will error on any slide which doesn't contain a shape named "Counter", and you will need to add logic to handle that condition, if it exists in your Presentation.

---

Bookmark this link, it's the PPT Object Model Reference which, while laborious to peruse, will explain just about anything you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743835(v=office.14).aspx

The hardest part (as a beginner) is knowing *what questions to ask*, and while the Object Model doesn't help you with that immediately, the more you browse it and search it, the more familiar you'll become with the different objects at your disposal, and what you can do with each of them.

If you're new to VBA entirely, also bookmark this list of VBA Statements. This has examples & definitions for all of the control flow & logic statements you might use in putting some code together.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx

This answer talks about how to run a macro automatically when changing slides, we'll use that approach for your problem. You'll use the `OnSlideShowPageChange` event because that's an *auto* macro and doesn't require the more complicated Application Class event handler.

[How to run a macro "OnEnterSlide" or "OnLeaveSlide" in Powerpoint VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979821/how-to-run-a-macro-onenterslide-or-onleaveslide-in-powerpoint-vba)

Implementing this is actually a moderately complicated problem and moreso for someone who is not familiar with VBA or PowerPoint's object model.

Now, you've mentioned a number of things which either are simply not true, or at the very least it is not intuitive or obvious why these must be true, when presented with alternatives:

> For that to work I would have to use a macro to add the shape to each slide individually. But then if I wanted to change the size of the shape I have to use code for that too. Not very elegant...would rather force the refresh somehow and use a master slide for the shape

(Note that the scope of your initial problem keeps increasing and becoming more complex).

> The reason is to make it easier to change the shape without using code and creating the shape in all the slides.

Sometimes this is the easiest or best way to do things, sometimes it's not. I am in no position to evaluate this with regards to your specific requirements, because you've given only 2 lines of code to examine, but from my vantage point, it seems you are hesitant to write more code because you simply don't know how.

I'm sorry but your deadline is not my problem, and I've spent a generous amount of time on this answer which I hope will at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: The counter needs to appear in all slides. For that to work I would have to use a macro to add the shape to each slide individually.
But then if I wanted to change the size of the shape I have to use code for that too.
Not very elegant...would rather force the refresh somehow and use a master slide for the shape.

Comment: Why not simply *move* the shape from slide to slide? That way it only needs to exist *once*, and you can have a small procedure (attached to the button) which moves it to whatever slide is viewed. Just a thought...

Comment: sounds great, can you give code examples to move a shape to the current slide in the same position and run it on slide change? 
I'm new to ppt vba and have a tight deadline, will try to figure it out.

Comment: @Tiago: there is a popular view here that requests for code samples are fairly transparent requests for free work. I advise you not to make such requests, since it can make a helper feel like they've wasted their time, if it seems to your helper that you were not going to apply the help anyway. Hope you can figure it out!

Comment: @DavidZemens +1 for explaining in detail to a newbie and being so patient.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, you may consider.
Add a button named Sh1, Sh2 in slide 2, Sh3 in slide 3 etc.
and attach all this shapes to the below code

```
For ctr = 1 To 3
If ActivePresentation.Slides(ctr).Shapes("sh" & ctr).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ctr Then
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End If
Exit Sub
Next
End Sub
```

This would check the current slide with the counter, if matches, moves next else exits.

Comment: You can simply create the shape in a similar loop @TiagoFreitas. This won't be part of your button code, but a simple macro that does a `For i = 1 to 400...` and creates (or copies existing shape) as needed.